# Postgresql exception (SUBQUERY IN FROM MUST HAVE AN ALIAS)

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I am trying to write down a query  BUT IT CONTINOUSLY GIVING ME THE ERROR even though everything seems alright. I am using Postgresql as Database.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l3s9.png)

Th query :

```
SELECT
    re.rad_exam_id
FROM
    rad_exam re
INNER JOIN discrete_task_assay  dta
    ON dta.task_assay_cd = re.task_assay_cd AND dta.default_result_type_cd = (?)
WHERE  re.order_id = (?)
ORDER  BY re.rad_exam_id
```

Th error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: Even with the useless parentheses around the `?` I very much doubt that this query will result in the error you mention.

Comment: What is the query actually sent to the database?  I don't know what your (unspecified) tool does to those question marks.

Comment: Those question mark is taking the values from the prepared statement..